# Syntax for explicit template specializations

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following is accepted by both gcc-4.9.2 and clang-3.8 when compiling as C++98 or C++11,

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T> void f(T) { printf("T\n"); }
template <> void f<int>(int) { printf("int\n"); }    // explicit specialization
template <> void f<>(double) { printf("double\n"); } // explicit specialization -- 14.7.2(7)
template <> void f(float) { printf("float\n"); }     // HERE

int main() {
  f(1L);    // T
  f(10);    // int
  f(10.0);  // double
  f(10.0F); // float
}
```

I see that in the C++11 standard §14.7.2(7) deducing trailing template arguments in explicit template specializations is permitted, but I cannot find whether or how the terser form marked `HERE` is allowed.

Are these compilers conformant or is this some extension?

Comment: None of those are explicit instantiations. They are explicit *specializations*.

Comment: @T.C. ups & thanks, fixed now.

Comment: I don't have the exact quote from the standard, but I remember that you can at least omit the angular brackets from a function call if the type can be deduced. Probably the same is allowed in specializations.

Comment: Actually, I just run this example on wandbox with gcc3.6.3 with c++03 and it is also accepted: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mVipI7Af0o5xm5CD#wandbox-resultwindow-code-body-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++14 standard §14.7(3) has

> An explicit specialization may be declared for a function template, a class template, a member of a class template or a member template. An explicit specialization declaration is introduced by template<>. In an explicit specialization declaration for a class template, a member of a class template or a class member template, the name of the class that is explicitly specialized shall be a simple-template-id. In the explicit specialization declaration for a function template or a member function template, the name of the function or member function explicitly specialized may be a template-id.

And then demonstrates

> ```
> template<class U> void g(U) { }
> template<> void g(char) { }       //specialize for U == char
>                                   // U is deduced from the parameter type
> ```

And then we have §14.7.3(10)

> A trailing template-argument can be left unspecified in the template-id naming an explicit function template specialization provided it can be deduced from the function argument type. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> class Array { / ... / };
> template<class T> void sort(Array<T>& v);
>
> // explicit specialization for sort(Array<int>&)
> // with deduced template-argument of type int
> template<> void sort(Array<int>&);
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Comment: That's interesting, C++14's §14.7.3(10) seems to have grown out of C++11's  §14.7.3(8) (well, N3376's) I was referring to, only that the example there reads `template void sort<>(Array<int>&);`.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier are you sure?  [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) copy of N3376 has the same 14.7.3(10).

Comment: even [n1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) from 2005 has it.

Comment: Yes sure now, but I mixed things up. There is a similar example in §14.7.2(7) (that's 2, not 3), but I do see exactly the §14.7.3(10) you quote. I think that answers this for C++11 as well, thanks!

Comment: I see now that §14.7.3 refers to specializations while §14.7.2 talks about instantiations. I think that was part of my confusion when looking this up.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Yeah the stuff still confuses me.  I keep a copy of the standard right on my desktop as I use it often enough.